# Xcode Run Script Not Working Properly

Tags: ios, xcode, bash

I have a run script in a framework which is responsible for building the xcode framework. It's work is simple to build the framework for both simulator and device, merge them and replace the existing framework at some location by the new one.

Here's how it replaces:

1. Create the path to where it should perform replace
2. Remove the existing framework folder from that path using (rm -rf)
3. Add the new framework.

Here, I am facing the issue, and that is (rm -rf) does not remove the existing framework folder, and because of which it is not able to update the new framework properly. Also, if i delete the framework manually from that path, it works perfect. I have checked the path too in terminal and there are no issues with it too.

Has someone encountered the same? How to fix this?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Could it be the problem with access?

I used  rm -v link/to/folder  to remove .framework folder.